# Angular doesnt update UI after data update inside it's own scope

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, ngrx

I'm pretty sure im missing out on something. As you see here I only have a subscription but also inside the component I make local changes with the typeWriter function which the UI doesnt update according to it. it only does when I use changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() which it doesnt look to be the best way when you make local changes.

```
    import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IconDefinition, faCopy } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { HotToastService } from '@ngneat/hot-toast';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { InitialState } from '../../../../../../store/store';
import { storeActions } from '../../../../../../store/store.actions';
import { selectPrinting } from '../../../../../../store/store.selectors';
import { MessageI } from './message.types';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrl: './message.component.scss',
})
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  /**
   * Chat object which contains properties {from & message}
   */
  @Input() chat: MessageI;
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  public printing$: boolean;

  public copyIcon: IconDefinition = faCopy;

  public copyIconStyle = {
    dimensions: {
      height: 20,
      width: 20,
    },
    style: { color: 'white', cursor: 'pointer', width: 'max-content' },
  };

  public setIntervalID: number;
  public printedMessage: string = '';

  get imageUrl(): string {
    return this.chat.from === 'You'
      ? 'assets/images/me.jpg'
      : 'assets/images/cat.png';
  }

  constructor(
    private toast: HotToastService,
    private store: Store<{ store: InitialState }>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.store.select(selectPrinting).subscribe((vl) => {
        this.printing$ = vl;
      })
    );

    if (this.chat.from === 'You') {
      this.printedMessage = this.chat.message;
      return;
    }

    this.typwriterEffect(50);

    this.store.dispatch(storeActions.printingHandler());
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((s) => s.unsubscribe());
  }

  copyMessage() {
    this.toast.success('Copied to clipboard!', {
      duration: 5000,
      style: {
        border: '1px solid #713200',
        padding: '16px',
        color: '#713200',
      },
      iconTheme: {
        primary: '#713200',
        secondary: '#FFFAEE',
      },
    });
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.chat.message);
  }

  typwriterEffect(speed: number) {
    // Has to be used from window otherwise theres typescript errors that it needs to be Nodejs.Timeout which prompts another error
    // conflicts with Nodejs enviroments
    this.setIntervalID = window.setInterval(() => {
      if (
        this.printedMessage.length !== this.chat.message.length &&
        this.printing$
      ) {
        this.printedMessage = this.chat.message.slice(
          0,
          this.printedMessage.length + 1
        );
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(storeActions.printingHandler());
        clearInterval(this.setIntervalID);
      }
    }, speed);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78070730?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the change detection cycle is not triggered when your observable is firing.
One way to get around to it is to use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to ensure that the change detection is triggered every time your observable fires.

In your example you could do something like this:

```
    this.printing$ = this.store.select(selectPrinting)
```

Instead of:

```
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.store.select(selectPrinting).subscribe((vl) => {
        this.printing$ = vl;
      })
    );
```

And in the HTML template:

```js
<ng-container *ngIf="printing$ | async as printing">
// the HTML code where printing is used,
// you can reference to it in the template as `printing`
</ng-container>
```

Also note that it is convention to name only `Observables` with the trailing "$".
And note that now that `printing$` is an `Observable`, you will need to make changes across the component to deal with that.

Comment: ```<div class="image-container">
  <img [src]="imageUrl" alt="" class="image" />
</div>
<div class="message-container">
  <b>
    <span class="from">{{ chat.from }}</span>
  </b>
  <span class="message">{{ printedMessage }}</span>
  <app-icon
    *ngIf="chat.from === 'You' ? true : !printing && chat.from === 'MeowGPT'"
    [icon]="copyIcon"
    (click)="copyMessage()"
    [dimensions]="copyIconStyle.dimensions"
    [style]="copyIconStyle.style"
  ></app-icon>
</div>```

It doenst work no. Also the issue it arises from the observable as it origins from the Typewriter

Comment: If you want an accurate response, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)